# B2C custom policy 'ignoring' claims exchange

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am following this guide

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/rest-api-claims-exchange-dotnet

However the code has been deprecated - IHttpActionResult no longer exists in latest version of Net Core

That means this response type now highlights as an error

```
if (inputClaims.firstName.ToLower() == "test")
        {
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, new B2CResponseContent("Test name is not valid, please provide a valid name", HttpStatusCode.Conflict));
        }
```

I believed that the method should become an ActionResult and return like this instead

```
if (inputClaims.firstName.ToLower() == "test")
        {
            return Ok(new B2CResponseContent("Test name is not valid, please provide a valid name", HttpStatusCode.Conflict));
        }
```

However, it appears if I do this, the policy simply ignores the error and carries on registering the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to return HTTP Status Code 409 (conflict). `return Ok(..)` will always return status code 200.

The correct way to return the response is:

```
if (inputClaims.firstName.ToLower() == "test")
{
       return Conflict(new B2CResponseContent("Test name is not valid, please provide a valid name", HttpStatusCode.Conflict));
}
```

or

```
if (inputClaims.firstName.ToLower() == "test")
{
       return StatusCode((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Conflict, new B2CResponseContent("Test name is not valid, please provide a valid name", HttpStatusCode.Conflict));
}
```